# Auto cleanup on server start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Is there a way to automatically trigger the options "Clean..." and "Clean Tomcat Work Directory" in Eclipse Oxygene everytime I start the server?
[image]

Comment: is there a way in any other version of eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own script at file `startup.sh` (macOS, Linux) or `startup.bat` (Windows).

If you use macOS or Linux, find file `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` at the below line

```
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
```

add these lines

```
cd ../work/
rm -rf *
cd ../bin/
```

on Windows, Find file `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat`, do similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know about Hot Deploy in Eclipse

1.Double clicks on the Tomcat plugin, refer to publishing tab, make sure Automatically publish when resources change is selected

2.In the Tomcat Plugin page, clicks on the Module view, make sure Auto Reload is Disabled. Default is enabled.

[Reference](https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/)